# TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)

Tags: typescript, settimeout

I am working on upgrading some old TypeScript code to use the latest compiler version, and I'm having trouble with a call to `setTimeout`.  The code expects to call the browser's `setTimeout` function which returns a number:

`setTimeout(handler: (...args: any[]) => void, timeout: number): number;`

However, the compiler is resolving this to the node implementation instead, which returns a NodeJS.Timer:

`setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: number, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timer;`

This code does not run in node, but the node typings are getting pulled in as a dependency to something else (not sure what).

How can I instruct the compiler to pick the version of `setTimeout` that I want?

Here is the code in question:

```
let n: number;
n = setTimeout(function () { /* snip */  }, 500);
```

This produces the compiler error:

> TS2322: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Do you have a types:["node"] in your tsconfig.json? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940954/cannot-find-namespace-nodejs-after-webpack-upgrade/43952363#43952363

Comment: @koe No, i don't have the types:["node"] option in the tsconfig file.  But the node types are getting pulled in as an npm dependency to something else.

Comment: You could also explicitly define "types" in tsconfig.json - when you omit "node" it isn't used in compilation. e.g. "types": ["jQuery"]

Comment: It is surprising that the answer of @koe (use "types" option) doesn't have any votes, being the only true correct answer.

Comment: @KevinTighe's `types` doesn't include `node` but `setTimeout` still gets its Node type rather than its browser type.  `types` defaults to all the types in `node_modules/@types`, as explained in https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types, but even if you _do_ specify `types` and _don't_ include `"node"`, why does `setTimeout` still get its Node type and how can you get the browser type?

@Axke's solution is a bit of a hack, basically saying it returns what it returns.  TypeScript may still be finding the wrong type, but at least it will be consistently wrong.

Comment: (setTimeout as Window["setTimeout"])

Comment: I have answered it in here, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455743/5405143

Answer (score 290, accepted):

**2021 update**

[Akxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56239226/3211932) suggests `ReturnType<Type>` technique introduced in Typescript 2.3:

```
let n: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
n = setTimeout(cb, 500);
```

It is nice and seems to be preferred over explicit casting. But the result type of "n" in this case is "NodeJS.Timeout", and it is possible to use it as follows:

```
let n: NodeJS.Timeout;
n = setTimeout(cb, 500);
```

The only problem with ReturnType/NodeJS.Timeout approach is that numeric operations in browser-specific environment still require casting:

```
if ((n as unknown as number) % 2 === 0) {
  clearTimeout(n);
}
```

**Original answer**

A workaround that does not affect variable declaration:

```js
let n: number;
n = setTimeout(function () { /* snip */  }, 500) as unknown as number;
```

Also, in browser-specific environment it is possible to use `window` object with no casting:

```js
let n: number;
n = window.setTimeout(function () { /* snip */  }, 500);
```

Comment: I think the other one (`window.setTimeout`) should be the correct answer for this question as it is the clearest solution.

Comment: If you are using the `any` type, you aren't really giving a TypeScript answer.

Comment: likewise the `number` type will lead to TypeScript specific lint errors, as the `setTimeout` function requires more than that.

Comment: `window.setTimeout` may cause issues with unit test frameworks (node.js). The best solution is to use `let n: NodeJS.Timeout` and `n = setTimeout`.

Comment: const timer = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval>>();

Comment: @amik, what about in a Service Worker?

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods you should be able to scope it again, but with `self` instead of `window` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172951/using-settimeout-in-a-serviceworker . Hopefully properly set up typescript will assign a proper type to it, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thanks @amik. A ServiceWorkerGlobalScope self does seem to work, though I was hoping that something that would work in both like globalThis might not have stupid node-specific defaults, so could be used in a library without nasty extra checks. Alas, it also has a stupid type...

Answer (score 569):

```ts
let timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = setTimeout(() => { ... });

clearTimeout(timer);
```

By using `ReturnType<fn>` you are getting independence from platform. You won't be forced to use neither `any` nor `window.setTimeout` which **will** break if you run the code on nodeJS server (eg. server-side rendered page).

---

Good news, this is also compatible with Deno!

Comment: My understanding is that this is the right answer and should be the accepted one, since it provides the right type definition for every platform supporting `setTimeout` / `clearTimeout` and does not use `any`.

Comment: This is the solution if you are writing a library that runs on both NodeJS and browser.

Comment: The return type is `NodeJS.Timeout` if using `setTimeout` directly and `number` if using `window.setTimeout`. Shouldn't need to use `ReturnType`.

Comment: @cchamberlain You need it as you run the `setTimeout` function and are expecting its result to be stored in the variable. Try it yourself in TS playground.

Comment: For the OP and me, TypeScript gets the type of `setTimeout` wrong (for reasons no-one can explain) but at least this solution should mask that in a slightly better way than just using `any`.

Comment: This solution works correctly for me. Without using this, my node app compiles correctly with TS, but when using Jest unit tests it chooses the incorrect window.setTimeout definition

Comment: When  clearTimeout  and setTimeout in different scope , it doesnt work for typescript 4.3.5

Comment: Didn't work in my Angular app,  the ansewr below (where you declare the type Timer, worked for me.

Answer (score 45):

I guess it depends on where you will be running your code.

If your runtime target is server side Node JS, use:

```
let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout;
global.clearTimeout(timeout);
```

If your runtime target is a browser, use:

```
let timeout: number;
window.clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 22):

This works perfectly well for me.

```
type Timer = ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>

const timer: Timer = setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)
```

Comment: Basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/56239226/3484824 which was posted almost 2 years earlier

Comment: @CanRau but for me it was still useful. Don't know why, but I failed to get the idea from the other answer, though, as I look at it now, it's not that voluminous.

Answer (score 14):

This will likely work with older versions, but with TypeScript version `^3.5.3` and Node.js version `^10.15.3`, you should be able to import the Node-specific functions from the [Timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) module, i.e.:

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers';
```

That will return an instance of [Timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) of type `NodeJS.Timeout` that you can pass to `clearTimeout`:

```
import { clearTimeout, setTimeout } from 'timers';

const timeout: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout(function () { /* snip */  }, 500);

clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Similarly, if you want the browser version of `setTimeout`, something like 
`const { setTimeout } = window` will clear up those errors.

Answer (score 9):

Wanted to mention as well that the spec for `NodeJS.Timeout` includes `[Symbol.toPrimitive](): number`:

```
interface Timeout extends Timer {
    /**
     * If true, the `Timeout` object will keep the Node.js event loop active.
     * @since v11.0.0
     */
    hasRef(): boolean;
    /**
     * Sets the timer's start time to the current time, and reschedules the timer to
     * call its callback at the previously specified duration adjusted to the current
     * time. This is useful for refreshing a timer without allocating a new
     * JavaScript object.
     *
     * Using this on a timer that has already called its callback will reactivate the
     * timer.
     * @since v10.2.0
     * @return a reference to `timeout`
     */
    refresh(): this;
    [Symbol.toPrimitive](): number;
}
```

And for compatibility, the other timeout APIs in Node work just fine with the plain integer ids, they don't need to accept the object. The objects are used "server"-side to allow some finer control over keeping the process alive and garbage collection stuff. For example:

```
function clearTimeout(timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | string | number | undefined): void;
```

This means you can use a primitive cast on the result of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`:

```
let timeoutId: number | undefined;
timeoutId = Number(setTimeout(callback, ms));

function clear() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}
```

Doesn't conflict with either API, while not running you into type trouble later on if you needed to depend on it being a primitive value for some other API contract.

Comment: thanks, Number() helped me to convert to number

Comment: This has a runtime cost, so we shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is not running in node and the node types are coming from a dependency.

- install `@types/web` if you haven't already
- create a file in your project e.g. `web-types.d.ts`
- at the top of the file add the line
  `/// <reference types="web" />`
- in your tsconfig under `compilerOptions` add
  `"typeRoots": ["./web-types", "./node_modules/@types"]`

This should prioritize browser types over node types.

Comment: ` // <reference types="web" /> ` is showing an error on 'web' `"Cannot find type definition file for 'web'"`

I installed @type/web via `npm install @typescript/lib-dom@npm:@types/web --save-dev`

Comment: adding @types/web solved it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting `setInterval` of `window`. Then you can also write it as

```
let timerId: number = setInterval((()=>{
    this.populateGrid(true)
  }) as TimerHandler, 5*1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting

###### tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

And create .d.ts

###### *.d.ts:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    type Timeout = number;
    type Timer = number;
}
```

typescript version 4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I was testing my Counter app using RTL and specifically was testing an element to be removed if count reaches 15. Since the component gets destroyed after running the test, setTimeout would still run after that and throw the error saying that React can't perform a state update on unmounted component. So, based on [dhilt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50428377/16364380), I was able to fix my useEffect cleanup function this way:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
const [bigSize, setBigSize] = useState(initialCount >= 15);

useEffect(() => {
    let id: NodeJS.Timeout;

    if(count >= 15) {
        id = setTimeout(() => setBigSize(true), 300);
    }

    return function cleanup() {
        clearTimeout(id);
    }
});
```

And here's the test suite:

```
describe('when the incrementor changes to 5 and "add" button is clicked', () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
            userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/Incrementor/), '{selectall}5');
            userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: "Add to Counter"}));
            await screen.findByText('Current Count: 15');
        })
            
        it('renders Current Count: 15', () => {
            expect(screen.getByText('Current Count: 15')).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
        
        it('renders too big and will dissapear after 300ms',async() => {
            await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByText(/size: small/i))
        });
        
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

TS2322: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.

The simple solution

abc : any;

for assgin

abc = setInterval or abc = setTimeout

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I faced the same problem and the workaround our team decided to use, was just to use "any" for the timer type. E.g.:

```
let n: any;
n = setTimeout(function () { /* snip */  }, 500);
```

It will work with both implementations of setTimeout/setInterval/clearTimeout/clearInterval methods.

Comment: Yeah, that does work.  I also realized that I can just specify the method on the window object directly:  window.setTimeout(...).  Not sure if that's the best way to go but I'll stick with it for now.

Comment: You can import the NodeJS namespace properly in typescript, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367655/23118).

Comment: To actually answer the question ("how can I instruct the compiler to pick the version I want"), you can use window.setTimeout() instead, as @dhilt answered below.

Comment: `window.setTimeout` may not work with unit test frameworks. There is a type that can be used here.. Its `NodeJS.Timeout`. You may think you're not in a node environment but I have news for you: Webpack / TypeScript etc. are executing node.js.

Comment: use of `any` is generally not the way to go.

Comment: @dedles, working solution with bad typing is better than not-working and perfectly typed one.

Comment: Yes but properly typed and and working is the best yet.

Comment: `any` defeats the whole purpose of typescript

Comment: @avalanche1 I kind of agree, but this is the case when I prefer avoiding "perfect theoretical" solutions and do "working practical" things. So instead of spending a lot of time figuring out the right typings and / or making the code hard to read by using complex Unions or similar approaches, we just make it work and go forward. If at any point in time there is a simple and easy-to-use solution, we just replace the "not-perfect-but-working" solution with the new better one.