# What return type should be used for setTimeout in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider following code:

```
const timer: number = setTimeout(() => '', 1000);
```

Typescript throws an error: `Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.` Quick lookup tells me that `setTimeout` returns `NodeJS.Timer`.

But if I am doing **browser-based development**, using `NodeJS.Timer` feels wrong. Which is the correct type definition or return type for making `setTimeout` work without resorting to `any` declaration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)

Answer (score 414, accepted):

Simplest solution is to allow type inference to work and not specify any type at all. If you need to specify a type, seeing as the type is not consistent between the browser and node declarations, you could use `ReturnType` to specify that the type of the variable is whatever the return type of `setTimeout` is:

```
const timer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = setTimeout(() => '', 1000);
```

Alternately, `window.setTimeout` can also be used instead of just `setTimeout`. It returns proper return type.

Comment: I tried to use window.setTimeout instead of setTimeout. window.setTimeout seems to return number as type. Is there any difference I should be aware of?

Comment: Titian, I'd up-vote this twice if I could, bless you!

Comment: As of 4.0.x, TypeScript will not compile if you try to pass `setTimeout()`’s return type to `clearTimeout()`, so casting to `number` will be required. This is probably a bug in TypeScript’s core type declarations.

Comment: q: What is the return type of setTimeout?
a: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>

Answer (score 73):

You can use `window.setTimeout` it returns a type of `number`.

```
let a: number;
a = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);
```

Answer (score 35):

This happens because Typescript will search for all type definitions under `node_modules/@types`

If you installed NodeJS type definition (comes with many npm packages) into `~/node_modules/@types/node/globals.ts` and your project is in `~/Projects/myproject`, the NodeJS definitions for `setTimeout` will leak.

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
> compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
> are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
> ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
> ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

If Typescript finds custom type definitions its is prioritized over the default type definitions.
[image: VS Code 2 type definitions of setTimeout()]

Solutions:

- Specify compilerOption which paths to search for type definitions: `"typeRoots":[]`
- Specify compilerOption which type definitions to load from the default paths: `"types": []`
- Remove the definitions file from the default search paths

Workaround:

- Use `window.setTimeout()` instead

Comment: This answer brings more solutions to the table instead of just “use window.setTimeout().”

Comment: Also, changing the code because incorrect type definitions leak into the project is not a solution. I'll change that.

Answer (score 4):

`window.setTimeout` returns `number`. Ideally, you want to define your own type to distinguish it from number (and prevent some ops like `+` which don't make sense for timers).

```
type TimerHandle = number;
```

Comment: In theory it is right but, TS is structural typing and not a normal typing. `type` is simply creating an alias. It won't still prevent. it.

Comment: All Typescript types (like generics, etc.) exist only in compile time, in the runtime you only have plain Javascript, so this is true for pretty much anything you do in Typescript.

Comment: @Dmitry the problem with your post is the phrase "prevent some ops like `+`" -- defining a type alias for `number` does not prevent using `+` either at compile time or runtime. You can add two `TimerHandle`s together and the code will compile and run just fine. There is some psychological prevention, however, since people might read that code and think they have some special "`TimerHandle`" type and not realize that it's actually just a number. So your answer is not wrong, just slightly misleading IMO.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this error what worked for me is adding in the tsconfig.js file:

```
"compilerOptions": {

   ...
   "types": [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### types when using the prefix window.

**setTimeout initialization** ( you can optionally initialize to `null` )

```
let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout | number | null = null;
```

**usage**

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(() => console.log("Timeout"), 1000);
```

**clear**

```
window.clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const timer:<NodeJS.Timer> = setTimeout(() => '', 1000);
```

NodeJS.Timer

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was working within Node, so I used `NodeJS.Timeout`

Comment: Care to comment on why this is downvoted? This worked for me and is also referenced in another answer that has upvotes.