# How do I use setTimeout with typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timeout

There is a sample of setTimeout using in angular and typescript:

```
let timer: number = setTimeout(() => {
}, 2000);
```

On compilation I get this message:

> error TS2322: Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Ho do I use setTimeout with typescript?

Comment: `let timer: Timeout = ...` maybe?

Comment: @mr_blond, May you please add the content of the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040703/what-return-type-should-be-used-for-settimeout-in-typescript

Comment: @Calculuswhiz in both nodejs and browser.

Comment: BTW, I suggest use timer rxjs operator

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this

```
let timer = setTimeout(() => {
}, 2000);
```