# Angular click debounce

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, debouncing

In my template I have a field and two buttons:

```
<div class="btn-plus" (click)="add(1)"> - </div>
<div class="txt"> {{ myValue }} </div>
<div class="btn-minus" (click)="add(-1)"> + </div>
```

In my component .ts file I have:

```
add(num) {
    this.myValue +=num;
    this.update(); // async function which will send PUT request
}
```

The `this.update()` function puts `myValue` in the proper field in a big JSON object and sends it to a server.

**Problem**: When a user clicks 10x in a short period of time on button plus/minus, then a request will be send 10 times. But I want to send a request only once - 0.5 sec after last click. **How to do it**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) operator :

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  calls = new Subject();

  service = {
    getData: () => of({ id: 1 }).pipe(delay(500)),
  };

  click() {
    this.calls.next(true);
    this.service.getData().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.calls),
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kffmtc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (open your console to check the logs)

Comment: In Stackblitz every time when I click  on "Simulate HTTP call" button i get immediately error "ERROR TypeError: _co.simulate is not a function"

Comment: Damn it, I renamed it --' Try again !

Comment: Now is ok. I give +1 (~15 min ago), however this solution in not so reusable as  Cory Rylan directive so I will not "check" it as best answer. But thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm not here to code a directive but to give you another lead, feel free to create a directive from that ! But I understand your position and I'm totally fine with it, even though the directive is way more complicated to use than that.

Comment: Can you please explain your solution a bit? It works but I can't make sense of it although I have checked the docs and played around with it.

Comment: I also don't fully understand why this works, if you want an easier to understand method that also uses rxjs check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76018715/3331025

Comment: Imo this solution is not the best one but here is the explanation :
- A click trigger "calls.next()", canceling all previous ongoing subscriptions because of the takeUntil()
- it subscribe again to getData(). Either it get canceled by a click or return the result.

Answer (score 8):

This is answer partially I found in internet, but I open to better solutions (or improve to below solution(directive)):

In internet I found `appDebounceClick` directive which helps me in following way:

I remove `update` from `add` in .ts file:

```
add(num) {
    this.myValue +=num;
}
```

And change template in following way:

```
<div 
    appDebounceClick 
    (debounceClick)="update()" 
    (click)="add(1)" 
    class="btn-plus"
    > - 
</div>
<div class="txt"> {{ myValue }} </div>
<!-- similar for btn-minus -->
```

### BONUS

Directive `appDebounceClick` written by [Cory Rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular) (I put code here in case if link will stop working in future):

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounceClick]'
})
export class DebounceClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() debounceTime = 500;
  @Output() debounceClick = new EventEmitter();
  private clicks = new Subject();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
      debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
    ).subscribe(e => this.debounceClick.emit(e));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using a simplified version of the `DebounceClickDirective` posted above. Since `debounceTime` operator doesn't support leading/trailing options, I decided to use `lodash`. **This eliminates the delay from click to action**, which in my case was opening a dialog and was pretty annoying.

Then I just use it like this `<button (debounceClick)="openDialog()">`

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

@Directive({
  selector: 'button',
})
export class DebounceClickDirective {
  @Output() debounceClick = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  debouncedClick = debounce(
    (event: Event) => {
      this.debounceClick.emit(event);
    },
    500,
    { leading: true, trailing: false },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A helper function --

```
export const debounced = (cb, time) => {
  const db = new Subject();
  const sub = db.pipe(debounceTime(time)).subscribe(cb);
  const func = v => db.next(v);

  func.unsubscribe = () => sub.unsubscribe();

  return func;
};
```

Then an example use could be:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { debounced } from 'src/helpers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  // Click calls `debouncedClick` instead of `myClick` directly
  template: '<button (click)="debouncedClick($event)">Click This</button>'
})
export class Example implements OnDestroy {
  debouncedClick; // Subject.next function

  constructor() {
    // Done in constructor or ngOnInit for `this` to resolve
    this.debouncedClick = debounced($event => this.myClick($event), 800);
  }

  // Called after debounced resolves (800ms from last call)
  myClick($event) {
    console.log($event);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Stay clean!
    this.debouncedFunc.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Could also reverse the usage, calling the 'myClick' on click and have the `debounced` callback perform the desired action. Dealer's choice.

Personally I this for `(keyup)` events as well.

Unsure if the unsubscribe is really necessary - was quicker to implement than to research the memory leak :)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this with a `setTimeout` if not want to use `rxjs observable` instance. This would be an ideal implementation with memory leak cleanup on `ngOnDestroy`:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-my",
  templateUrl: "./my.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my.component.sass"],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  timeoutRef: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

  clickCallback() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutRef);
    this.timeoutRef  = setTimeout(()=> {
      console.log('finally clicked!')
    }, 500);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutRef);
  }
}
```

Edit:
Updated timeoutRef TS def to safer one as suggested by [@lord-midi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337906/lord-midi) on the comments.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to use "NodeJS.Timeout" inside of an Angular application.

Comment: Hi, just did some research and found the following resources that suggest otherwise. The issue is not related to Angular2 apps but a Typescript discussion that can apply to other frameworks. Still, will update accordingly to a "safer"  types definition. 


1. [Typescript: What is the correct type for a Timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245787/typescript-what-is-the-correct-type-for-a-timeout)


2. [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout node vs window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)

Answer (score 1):

> On Click event fir only first time so you don't need to wait for last click. OR how to ignore subsequent events ?

Solution by [Ondrej Polesny](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/author/ondrej/) on [freecodecamp Website](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/)
Also thanks to [Cory Rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular) for nice explanation about Debouncer

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounceClick]'
})

export class DebounceClickDirective {

  @Input() debounceTime: number = 800;
  @Output() debounceClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  private onClickDebounce = this.debounce_leading(
    (e) => this.debounceClick.emit(e), this.debounceTime
  );

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onClickDebounce(event);
  }

  private debounce_leading(func: any, timeout: number) {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
      if (!timer) {
        func.apply(this, args);
      }
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        timer = undefined;
      }, timeout);
    };
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler to understand option is to use a custom subject that emits on click and simply use rxjs native `debounceTime`.
Live Example (open console logs):
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8kmhw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
// declare these variables
clicker = new Subject();
clicker$ = this.clicker.asObservable();

//Add to ngOnInit(), change the number according to how sensitive you want to debounce
this.clicker$.pipe(debounceTime(200)).subscribe(() => {
     console.log('Requesting Data ...');
     this.service.getData().subscribe((d) => console.log(d));
});

// your button's (click) function:
this.clicker.next(true);
```