# Modal Controller does not generate modal with 'Loading chunk N failed'

Tags: angular, webpack, ionic4

## Set up

I have a component named `InputAutocomplete` that when clicked, uses the `ModalController` to open a modal. That modeluses a custom component `PageAutocompleteComponent` as its template.

### Problem

My problem is, when I click the `InputAutocomplete` button, **sometimes the modal shows up and sometimes it doesn't**.

I've been so hesitant to ask for help here in Stack Overflow because it's so difficult for me to explain what the problem is (because I also have difficulty reliably replicating the issue).

Also, when this bug occurs, my emulator doesn't refresh with code changes anymore. Opening alerts using `AlertController` also no longer works.

### Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (F:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.9.0) : 0.8.1
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0)  : 0.2.9

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\Users\Darren\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (C:\nProgram Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.10.3
   OS                : Windows 10
```

## Errors

### Error messages

The error messages I get follow these patterns:

1. `Loading chunk 40 failed.`
2. `Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined`

These look like very deep errors in angular, or possibly webpack, which makes it daunting for me to try to fix. I don't even know where to start.

### Error log

The error log on Chrome Dev Tools shows the following:

```
input-autocomplete: Getting top modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Generating a new modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Getting top modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Generating a new modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Getting top modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Generating a new modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Getting top modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Generating a new modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Getting top modal...
consolelogs.js:49 input-autocomplete: Generating a new modal...
5consolelogs.js:49 Error: Loading chunk 40 failed.
(timeout: http://localhost:8100/40.js)
    at requireEnsure (bootstrap:126)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext (.*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$ exclude: \.system\.entry\.js$ namespace object:393)
    at loadModule (core-ca0488fc.js:75)
    at initializeComponent (core-ca0488fc.js:1710)
    at nextTick (core-ca0488fc.js:1851)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone.scheduleMicroTask (zone-evergreen.js:855)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
(anonymous) @ consolelogs.js:49
consoleError @ core-ca0488fc.js:63
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:855
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:469
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:454
timer @ zone-evergreen.js:2650
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:2671
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:378
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMacroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:234
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone-evergreen.js:1107
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:2686
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone-evergreen.js:1428
requireEnsure @ bootstrap:145
webpackAsyncContext @ .*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$ exclude: \.system\.entry\.js$ namespace object:393
loadModule @ core-ca0488fc.js:75
initializeComponent @ core-ca0488fc.js:1710
nextTick @ core-ca0488fc.js:1851
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:855
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
nextTick @ core-ca0488fc.js:156
(anonymous) @ core-ca0488fc.js:95
then @ core-ca0488fc.js:1219
then @ core-ca0488fc.js:1341
scheduleUpdate @ core-ca0488fc.js:1219
setValue @ core-ca0488fc.js:1378
set @ core-ca0488fc.js:1403
(anonymous) @ fesm5.js:1453
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:34127
set @ fesm5.js:1450
updateProp @ core.js:28067
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:27753
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:38472
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:38411
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:39433
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:39376
(anonymous) @ SelectTextComponent.html:21
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:39364
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38376
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:38699
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38377
callViewAction @ core.js:38742
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:38670
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:38383
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:39716
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:39299
detectChanges @ core.js:27092
tick @ core.js:35380
_zone.run @ core.js:35228
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:34201
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:34066
next @ core.js:35225
schedulerFn.__isAsync @ core.js:31051
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ spy-core.js:478
notify_ @ spy-core.js:443
next @ spy-core.js:478
next @ spy-core.js:526
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:31013
checkStable @ core.js:34144
onHasTask @ core.js:34221
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:411
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:431
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:272
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:372
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
resolvePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:791
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:707
Promise.then (async)
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:1033
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:876
Ctor.then @ zone-evergreen.js:1032
resolvePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:758
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:707
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:72
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:876
step @ tslib.es6.js:72
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.js:73
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:876
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.js:69
presentModal @ input-autocomplete.ts:59
(anonymous) @ InputAutocomplete.html:2
handleEvent @ core.js:38098
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:39716
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:39352
dispatchEvent @ core.js:25818
(anonymous) @ core.js:27715
schedulerFn.__isAsync @ core.js:31094
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ spy-core.js:478
notify_ @ spy-core.js:443
next @ spy-core.js:478
next @ spy-core.js:526
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:31013
subscription.clicks.pipe.subscribe.e @ DebounceClickDirective.ts:27
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ spy-core.js:478
notify_ @ spy-core.js:443
next @ spy-core.js:478
next @ spy-core.js:526
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
debouncedNext @ debounceTime.js:40
dispatchNext @ debounceTime.js:53
_execute @ AsyncAction.js:51
execute @ AsyncAction.js:39
flush @ AsyncScheduler.js:33
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:34182
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:454
timer @ zone-evergreen.js:2650
setInterval (async)
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:2671
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:378
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:272
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:372
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMacroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:234
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone-evergreen.js:1107
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:2686
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone-evergreen.js:1428
requestAsyncId @ AsyncAction.js:25
schedule @ AsyncAction.js:21
schedule @ Scheduler.js:7
schedule @ AsyncScheduler.js:21
_next @ debounceTime.js:28
next @ Subscriber.js:49
(anonymous) @ spy-core.js:478
notify_ @ spy-core.js:443
next @ spy-core.js:478
next @ spy-core.js:526
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
clickEvent @ DebounceClickDirective.ts:38
(anonymous) @ InputAutocomplete.html:2
handleEvent @ core.js:38098
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:39716
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:39352
dispatchEvent @ core.js:25818
(anonymous) @ core.js:37030
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:1789
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:391
onInvokeTask @ core.js:34182
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:390
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:168
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:465
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
5consolelogs.js:49 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined
    at initializeComponent (core-ca0488fc.js:1715) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined
    at initializeComponent (http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:107818:24)
```

[image: Loading chunk failed- cannot read isProxied of undefined]

### `onClick` function

This is what the click function looks like:

```js
  async presentModal() {
    this.Sulat.debug("Getting top modal...");

    const topModal = await this.modalController.getTop();

    if (isNonNullAndUndefined(topModal)) {
      this.Sulat.debug("Dismissing existing modal...");
      await topModal.dismiss();
    }

    this.Sulat.debug("Generating a new modal...");
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: PageAutocompleteComponent,
      componentProps: {
        initialChoices: this.initialChoices,
        values: this.values,
        selectedValue: this.selectedValue
      }
    });

    this.Sulat.debug("Modal generated.");

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(({ data }) => {
      this.Sulat.debug("Input-autocomplete modal dismissed.");
      if (data && data.hasOwnProperty("label")) {
        this.selectedValue = data;
        this.modelChanged(data);
      }
    });

    this.Sulat.debug("Presenting modal.");
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

And this is how it is called on the HTML, with [debounce click functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319598/1323398):

```
<div appDebounceClick [debounceTime]="200" (debounceClick)=presentModal()>
   ...
</div>
```

### Hypotheses

Here are my potential guesses as to why this error occurs:

1. It might be related to Webpack because it's talking about loading chunks. Could it possibly be related to hot module reload? Like possibly the web server thinks I applied some changes on my IDE and it was trying to reload data? I highly think it is related to webpack or something because my code changes don't reload the emulator anymore.
2. It might be related to `ModalController`, because the modal isn't being generated or it's not showing up. I don't know.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Turning off the `--live-reload` flag when running on the emulator stopped the loading chunks error. However, this slows down my development since I have to keep restarting the build and etc.