# Typescript: What is the correct type for a Timeout?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the correct type when dealing with timers? I have tried `Timeout` and `number`

```
  let debounceResize: any;
//                     ^ What should this be?
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    clearTimeout(debounceResize);
    debounceResize = setTimeout(calcCanvasSize, 500);
  });
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In a NodeJS context, you can use `NodeJS.Timeout` instead of `Timeout`. A prerequisite for that is to have run `npm install @types/node --save-dev`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For this case, I will give you 2 options:

1. Define type of `debounceResize` as return type of `setTimeout`, use `ReturnType` native generic.

```
let debounceResize: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
```

2. Use `window.setTimeout` instead of only `setTimeout`. `window.setTimeout` returns a number.

```
let debounceResize: number;

debounceResize = window.setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 10):

**In a Web Browser** app, [`setTimeout` returns a `number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

This setup requires the `DOM` library (or equivalent).

[image]

**In a NodeJS** app, [`setTimeout` returns a `NodeJS.Timeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args).

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev`.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried adding the type number and I get this error:  Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: @Bill If you are receiving the error `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'`, then you are in a NodeJS context, and can use the type `NodeJS.Timeout`.

Comment: I'm using create react app with tsconfig: "lib": ["dom","dom.iterable","esnext"],

Comment: @Bill It seems like you have a mix of NodeJS type definitions and Web Browser (`dom`) type definitions. The suggestion by `hoangdv` to use `window.setTimeout` seems to work to force the use of the `dom` implementation of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

Update to the answer. This is now available.

```
let debounceResize: NodeJS.Timeout = setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
```

Comment: should be fine while developing a nodejs application not working with browser

Comment: @dyaa Well you wouldn't be using typescript in the browser. And I have this working fine on my React project.

Answer (score 1):

`NodeJS.Timeout`,
worked for me. You can also check by hovering over the

```js
setTimout(() => ..., delay)
```

typescript usually show the return type