# what type should timeout be defined at in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a debounce function in typescript, but am unsure of what type to set a variable that is assigned to `setTimeout`. My code looks like this:

```
function debounced(func: () => void, wait: number) {
    // what type should timeout be here?
    let timeout: any;
    return () => {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            func();
        }, wait);
    };
}
```

Comment: looks like `NodeJS.Timeout` does it. Is this correct?

Comment: If `timeout` is the ID of the timer, then it's a number.

Comment: If I set it to `number` I see the following error in the console - `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'.` ‍♂️

Comment: That error tells you the type is `Timeout`. Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah, I have tried that - that gives the error - `Cannot find name 'Timeout'.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)

Answer (score 16):

If you want your code to be portable between node.js and browser environment, you can use the return type of `setTimeout` like this:

```
let timeout: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
```

because it's declared to return different types in node and browser.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am only using it in the browser tbh.

Comment: Then in the browser, it's just `number`. If you get an error about `Type Timeout`, then probably some other code you referenced somewhere is pulling in node.js typings.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript prioritizes custom type definitions over default types.

If your tsconfig.json file contains `types: node`, it is telling Typescript to use the `setTimeout(): NodeJS.Timeout` found in **node_modules/@types/node** instead of the default `setTimeout(): number` method.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node",
      ...
    ]
}
```

If you don't explicitly need that type option, remove it and this error will go away:

```
"compilerOptions": {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just using the browser, explicitly calling `window.setTimeout` should solve this.

Answer (score -1):

You could try with using **window.setTimeout** instead of just setTimeout, this way the typescript one will be explicitly used