# Why does ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> differ from return type of setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am creating a hook but it's failing typing.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function useTimeoutEffect<TArgs extends any[]>(
  callback: (...args: TArgs) => void,
  ms?: number,
  ...args: TArgs
): void {
  const timeoutRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeoutRef.current !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Timeout' on next line.
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(callback, ms, args);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
      timeoutRef.current = undefined;
    };
  }, [ms, args]);
}
```

- I used [`ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934874/242042)
- I don't explicitly add [`{types: node}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63909124/242042)

My tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/test-support/*"
  ]
}
```

I do have `@types/node` in my node_modules but it appears to be added by jest.

For now I worked aounrd it by typecasting as `any` but I'd like to avoid that.

```
timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(callback, ms, args) as any;
```

The full error is

```
$ C:\p\spring-docker\node_modules\.bin\tsc
src/useTimeoutEffect/useTimeoutEffect.ts:19:5 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'.

19     timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(callback, ms, args);
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in src/useTimeoutEffect/useTimeoutEffect.ts:19
```

Code in https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks/blob/master/src/useTimeoutEffect/useTimeoutEffect.ts

I also tried explicitly [emptying the types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856713/242042) by adding the following to tsconfig.json and still the same error.

```
"types": []
```

Comment: What is the full error? Works fine here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UBKFgFcBOA7G4IB5RIB7AMygGdUYBLAWwmLWAD4AoNgY2KwuCgAeALlgJK1eo2YAKaQEoELKAG8AvnLZA

Comment: I know, I think it may be something to do with jest adding `@types/node` and typescript implicitly using it.