# "TS2322: Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'" when running unit tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have two TypeScript packages, and one package (Package A) depends on the other (Package B). Each package has a unit test set up using Karma. When I run unit tests for each individually after installing all dependencies from NPM, the unit tests run fine. However, if I use `npm link package-b` in Package A and run Package A's unit tests then, I get the error stated in the title: "TS2322: Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'."

The line in question is a call to `setTimeout`. After digging, I found that while running the tests separately without `npm link`, TypeScript correctly identifies the `setTimeout` signature in `typescript/lib/lib.dom` as the desired type, but in the failing case after using `npm link` it is using using Node's `setTimeout` signature in `@types/node/index`. I confirmed this by changing the return type on `setTimeout` to `string` and observing the same error with `string` in the place of `Timeout`.

What I am not certain of is *why* the TypeScript compiler has decided to use the alternative definition in this specific case, nor how I can convince it to use the desired definition. I am happy to post some code, but I am not sure what would be useful in this case given all that is on the failing line is the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You could try with using `window.setTimeout` instead of just setTimeout, this way the typescript one will be explicitly used

Comment: This worked...but if I am in a '.tsx' file in React...why wouldn't TS imply `window` without having to do this?

Comment: And in case of React Native?

Comment: Looks like TS assumes we're in a Node environment, since there setTimeout returns a Timeout object

Comment: @user123444555621 NodeJS doesn't assume you're in Node all the time, only when `@types/nodes` are a dependency (whether or not we're in a `.tsx`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856713/8186898) for more details and a fix

Comment: global.setTimeout - worked for me

Comment: thanks for the answer it resolved the issue for me. could you explain why it works?

Answer (score 147):

You can use:

```
let timeoutId: null | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = null
...
timeoutId = setTimeout(...)
```

It'll pick correct declaration depending on your context.

I'm seeing this discrepency when using vscode/tsc (NodeJS.Timeout) and running ts-jest (number). This is the only way the whole thing typechecks on both sides.

Comment: But what if you also need to call `clearTimeout`? (e.g. when the reason to even use `setTimeout` was for debouncing) 
In my situation for some reason TS expects `setTimeout` to return `NodeJS.Timeout` but it also still expects `clearTimeout` to receive a number...

Comment: If you need to use `clearTimeout()` you can just cast the variable to a `Number()`: `clearTimeout(Number(timeoutId))`

Comment: for me `let timeout: string | number | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;` worked. I am creating a debounce function.

Comment: If you plan to use `clearTimeout` it is better here to use `undefined | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;`

Answer (score 47):

By default, typescript [includes all `./node_modules/@types/*`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types). If you have `./node_modules/@types/node` there, its timeout typings will override the web typing (that returns a number, and not a `NodeJS.Timeout`).

You can remedy to that by explicitly emptying your types in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": []
  }
}
```

Realistically you're probably in a project where you need other types and libs so you might wanna bring back ES and DOM libs:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Bothers me that this is not the accepted answer. That accepted answer feels incredibly like the StackOverflow stereotype of: "Q: How do I use X? A: You don't, use Y instead, using X is dumb."

Comment: What to do, if you already have some types included in your project, so you can't reset them, but still doesn't work?
The solution I came up with is 

timeOut = setTimeout(...) as unknown as number;

Thereby trying to tell the compiler that setTimeout indeed returns a number here. 
The 'as unknown' is needed, because otherwise ts complains that there is no overlap between the types.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'd rather use several tsconfigs per env (one for tests, one for backend, etc), which all extend from a base config, but each with different `.compilerOptions.types`

Comment: I tried this but it still picks up node typings. It's in create-react-app project if it matters.

Comment: `"types": []` doesn't work for me, there is a bug
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37708
But it may start working in TS v5
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51715

Comment: Works in typescript v5.3.2 (and possibly v5.x)

Answer (score 10):

Adds to **Mirek Rusin** answer.

For calls `clearTimeout` you should to use type `undefined` instead of `null`

```js
 let timeoutId: undefined | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

 timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
   // ...
 }, 1000);

 clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Comment: I love this solution. I didn't realize typescript had a ReturnType utility method. That is genious. It solves the Node / Browser incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

### types when using prefix window.

**setTimeout initialization** ( you can optionally initialize to `null` )

```
let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout | number | null = null;
```

**usage**

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(() => console.log("Timeout"), 1000);
```

**clear**

```
window.clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 timer: NodeJS.Timeout |  number;
```

It works for me in Angular 15

Answer (score -4):

You can use something like:

```
let myTimeOut: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;

myTimeOut = setTimeout(...);
```

Then when you reset your variable to initial status, you can simply:

```
myTimeOut = null;
```

Answer (score -4):

For me helped `"strict": false` in tsconfig.json

Comment: Very bad solution. You don't solve types problem, you just disable checks.