# How to define type with function overriding?

Tags: javascript, typescript

To give a little background i was initially facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071901/9816472) and as shared by the solution, it make sense to let the type to be flexible depending on the context

However, I found out that it isnt really working on my end

```js
let timeoutId: null | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = null

timeoutId = setTimeout(...)
```

With the code above, i'm getting `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'.ts(2322)`.

When I hover over `timeoutId`, I got `let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout | null`, while hovering over `setTimeout`, i see below

```js
function setTimeout(handler: any, timeout?: any, ...args: any[]): number (+2 overloads)
namespace setTimeout
```

Is there any way to go about it? I think the root cause is due to function overriding

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WKqVGN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: What do you mean by "overriding" here?  [Overriding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#overriding-methods) is not the same thing as [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads); do you maybe mean "overloading" instead?

Comment: Is this code in a browser or node environment?

Comment: @jcalz: it is not reproducible on TS playground because the absence of `@types/node` in the node_modules, I've mentioned in the question that timeoutId will be inferred to `let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout|null`

Comment: @kellys: It should be NodeJS, but when I hover over `setTimeout`, TS thinks that it is on browser, that's why it's showing `function setTimeout(...): number`?

Comment: @Isaac yes, you might need to modify the example code to make it reproducible in a standalone IDE.  If you do that, you'll be more likely to get a useful answer than if you rely on others to either do it themselves or make untested suggestions.