# Using setTimeout in a ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In my `ServiceWorker` I have the following code:

```
function send_alert() {
    console.log('alert');
};


self.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
    console.log("message:" + evt.data);
    self.setTimeout(1000*5, send_alert);
    console.log("done");
});
```

If a button is clicked in the main page, a message is send to the worker. This works fine and I see the `message: ...` and `done` logs in the console. The `self.setTimeout` call does not raise an error, but `send_alert` is never called.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope implements `WindowTimers` which implements `setTimeout`. `self` should be an instance of `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`, so I don't see the problem. What's the proper way to use `setTimeout` in a service worker?

Comment: It should work, unless *5 is really something >60 on Chrome or >30 on Firefox. I guess "self" is the global object in SW but try dropping the qualification and try again.

Comment: The order of the parameters is wrong. First comes the callback, then the time - not vice-versa  (at least if this is the normal setTimeout function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed the `self.setTimeout` function is the normal `setTimeout` function, then the order of the parameters is wrong: You first have to provide the callback, then the number of milliseconds.

This is, unfortunately, counterintuitive to what's seen as de-facto standard in JavaScript today, but `setTimeout` is pretty old, so… historical reasons