# TS2769: How to fix "clearTimeout" with return value from setTimeout in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In "normal" JavaScript, I can do the following:

```
var timer = setTimeout( myFunc, 1000 );
clearTimout(timer);
```

But in TypeScript, the setTimeout-Function has a strange return value `NodeJS.Timer`, which can't be used for `clearTimeout` since clearTimeout requires a number.

How to fix that?

After some research I found the following type-cast:

```
let timer: null | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = null;
timer = setTimeout( myFunc, 1000 );
```

However, calling

```
clearTimeout(timer)
```

via TypeScript gives the following error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(timeoutId: Timeout): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Timeout | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Timeout'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(handle?: number | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Timeout | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.
```

Comment: `But in TypeScript, the setTimeout-Function has a strange return value NodeJS.Timer, which can't be used for clearTimeout since clearTimeout requires a number.` clearTimeout accepts the value returned by `setTimeout`.

Comment: You specified that timer can be null, but overload 1 (taking Timeout) does not accept null. Either assign in one statement, or use a null guard (if statement)

Comment: "*But in TypeScript, the setTimeout-Function has a strange return value `NodeJS.Timer`*" - no. It has that return type in Node.js, and it seems you have configured your Typescript to assume a node environment. And in node, `clearTimeout` also accepts such a timer object.

Comment: @delete what's the contents of your `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 4):

Add guard against null:

```js
let timer: null | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = null;
timer = setTimeout( myFunc, 1000 );

if (timer) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: In new TypeScript you can replace condition with ```!``` It says to TypeScript - everything is fine, I am sure it is not null or undefined
 ```clearTimeout(timer!);```

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking for answer, you need to mention that you are accessing timeouts from window object instead of node

```js
const { setTimeout, clearTimeout } = window

const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
... timeout code here
}, timeoutInMilliSeconds)


// Clear out the timer later
clearTimeout(timerID)
```

[TS playground with window object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=99&strict=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCWBbApgJwJIBEYF4YHd4wATEfAOgmSgBUlkQBXKAChYEpcA%20GAbwFgAUDBihIIADbJyEkAHMWAcgASyCbIIhUE4hEXshAXwA0MAIwAGKwcFDCJMuWBSAhqjoomrBCgyZ2QA)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I should have taken the clue that the return value of `setInterval()` was a NodeJS value.

Answer (score -1):

I got the similar problem and managed to fix it with [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)
to tell the compiler that "the expression cannot be null or undefined"

```
let timer: null | ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = null;
timer = setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);

clearTimeout(timer!);
```