# Typescript lib for functions shared between Node and client-side?

Tags: javascript, typescript

By default, TS doesn't include types for common JS functions like `setTimeout`, or `console.log`. I get that technically these aren't part of ECMAScript, so that's why they're not included. They're included in my client-side environment with `lib: ['dom']` and server environment `types: ['node']`.

I have some JS files that are shared between Node and client-side. If I want to use `setTimeout` etc, I need to do something like:

```
import type { setTimeout as _setTimeout } from 'timers';

declare global {
  const setTimeout: typeof _setTimeout;
}
```

or

```
import '@types/node/timers.d';
```

However, both of these have issues. The first one causes "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'setTimeout'" and the second one makes me use Node types for client-side code.

Is there a good way to use these common JS functions in shared code?

Comment: Why do you need to `import '@types/node/timers.d'`? I thought `setTimeout` was globally declared with `@types/node`. And what is the `'timers'` module?

Comment: So, you want a shared function to return one type if it's client side and another type if it's server side?

Comment: Actually nodejs `setTimeout` has a *different* type than dom `setTimeout`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - use correct version of setTimeout (node vs window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802988/typescript-use-correct-version-of-settimeout-node-vs-window)